# Filter data through rails controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, models

I need to apply a query filter to my data to match the foreign key of one table to the primary key of the other table, and I'd like to do it through the controller for now. Document is the main table/model. Keyword is another model but is also a subtable of Document. Looking for advice on syntax for this.

An example would:

```
@keywords = Keyword.where(keywordable_id == @document.id)
```

keywordable_id is the foreign key from the Document model/table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from

`@keywords = Keyword.where(keywordable_id == @document.id)`

to

`@keywords = Keyword.where(keywordable_id: @document.id)`

On the other hand, I suggest you to set association

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keywords, foreign_key: 'keywordable_id'
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document, primary_key: 'keywordable_id'
end
```

query `@keywords = @document.keywords`

Read more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html